# ArrayWritable contstructor

Tags: java, hadoop, constructor, mapreduce, writable

I'm trying to create a mapreduce chain composed of two steps. The first reduce emit key-value pairs as (key, value) where value is a list of custom object and the second mapper should read the output of the first reducer. The list is a custom ArrayWritable. Here is the relevant code:

```
 class MyArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {  

    public MyArrayWritable() {
        super(Custom.class);
    }

    public MyArrayWritable(Writable[] values) {
        super(Custom.class, values);
    }

    @Override
    public Custom[] get() {
        return (Custom[]) super.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return Arrays.toString(get());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        super.write(arg0);
    }
}
```

Second mapper (takes custom arraywritable as value):

```
 public static class SecondMapper extends Mapper<Text, MyArrayWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void map(Text key, MyArrayWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //other code
        context.write(key, myNewWritableArray);
    }
}
```

When the second job starts, I get this error:
           Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Detector$MyArrayWritable.< init >()

How can I solve it? I've have already implemented the default constructor inside MyArrayWritable

Comment: Is this an existing framework?  Which one?  Or are you just rolling your own map-reduce here?

Comment: @markspace I'm using apache mapreduce framework (2.7.1)

Comment: Is Apache mapreduce perchance better known as Apache Hadoop? http://hadoop.apache.org/  Or are you saying that you are literally using only the MapReduce part of their code base?  Are you using any other frameworks besides their map-reduce?

Comment: @markspace apache Hadoop

Comment: @ben I've already seen that post and I implemented an empty constructor (as you can see in MyArrayWritable)

Comment: Have you declared all inner classes throughout your job as static, as per the highest-voted answer?

Comment: @ben I have an enclosing class Detector and 6 inner classes: the mappers and reducers, Custom and MyWritableArray, so I have to declare Custom and MyWritableArray as static?

Comment: Yep that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: @ben It's working! Thank you!